# BeautifulSoup getting href

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I have the following `soup`:

```
<a href="some_url">next</a>
<span class="class">...</span>
```

From this I want to extract the href, `"some_url"`

I can do it if I only have one tag, but here there are two tags. I can also get the text `'next'` but that's not what I want.

Also, is there a good description of the API somewhere with examples. I'm using [the standard documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), but I'm looking for something a little more organized.

Comment: Please post a code sample to show how you're trying to do it

Comment: Alright, I figured it out:

    soup.find('a')['href']

The thing that confused me was that I was using django (html) to see it, which actually removes the href before presenting it:  soup.find('a') becomes only 'next'

Comment: True, this question is a duplicate. Yet the beauty of @MarkLongair's answer makes it precious, even a few years later.

Answer (score 543):

You can use `find_all` in the following way to find every `a` element that has an `href` attribute, and print each one:

```
# Python2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    
html = '''<a href="some_url">next</a>
<span class="class"><a href="another_url">later</a></span>'''
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']

# The output would be:
# Found the URL: some_url
# Found the URL: another_url
```

```py
# Python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="https://some_url.com">next</a>
<span class="class">
<a href="https://some_other_url.com">another_url</a></span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])

# The output would be:
# Found the URL: https://some_url.com
# Found the URL: https://some_other_url.com
```

Note that if you're using an older version of BeautifulSoup (before version 4) the name of this method is `findAll`. In version 4, BeautifulSoup's method names [were changed to be PEP 8 compliant](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names), so you should use `find_all` instead.

---

If you want *all* tags with an `href`, you can omit the `name` parameter:

```
href_tags = soup.find_all(href=True)
```

Comment: can you get the single href with the class "class="class""

Comment: @yoshiserry soup.find('a', {'class': 'class'})['href']

Comment: How do you attenuate false positives and unwanted results (i.e. `javascript:void(0)`, `/en/support/index.html`, `#smp-navigationList`)?

Comment: Hello how can I get the 'next' value in href.
```<a href="some_url">NEXT</a>```

Comment: @abdoulsn `soup.find('a').contents[0]`

Comment: I believe in your last line, href needs to be a string 'href'