# How to extract a href link from anchor tags in beautiful soup

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, href, urllib2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

I am using beautiful soup and below is my code

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen("some_url")
html_data = data.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
href_tags = soup.findAll('a')
```

**result:**

```
href_tags = 
[<a href="http://www.exampl.com/score_card" target="_blank" style="font-family:arial;color:#192e94;">Click Here</a>, 
<a href="https://example.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=5">what is this</a>,
<a href="https://example.com/search?pr=6">Cool</a>,
<a href="https://example.com/help/host/search?pr=7">Hello</a>]
```

But actually i want href from all anchor tags , how can i extract href tags.

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: this one may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup

Comment: @novus42: Thanks very much that gives more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping over the matches:

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen("some_url")
html_data = data.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)

for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    print a['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head - `href_tags = [tag['href'] for tag in soup.findAll('a', {'href': True})]`

The `{'href': True}` ensures there is an href attribute so that the `tag.attr['href']` doesn't fail.