# BeautifulSoup: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need  take **"href"** attribute from a link (**a**) tag.

I run

```
 label_tag = row.find(class_='Label')
 print(label_tag)
```

and I get (sorry, I can't show link and text for privacy reasons)

```
<a class="Label" href="_link_">_text_</a>
```

of **type**

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

but when I run (as shown at [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href) )

```
tag_link = label_tag['href']
print(tag_link)
```

I guess the following error (on first command)

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

**[SOLVED] EDIT**: I was making a mistake (looping over elements with heterogeneous structure)

Comment: Could you show the complete code you have at the moment? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that `label_tag` isn't actually returning the part of the soup you are looking for. This minimal example works:

```
import bs4
text = '''<a class="Label" href="_link_">_text_</a>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
link = soup.find("a",{"class":"Label"})
print (link["href"])
```

Output:

```
_link_
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. I was making a mistake (looping over elements with heterogeneous structure). now it works. thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

beacuse in `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, there is no class of "Label", so label_tag['href'] return None, than an error is occured.

you can use to following code to handle this exception:

```
if tag_link = label_tag.get('href'):
    print(tag_link)
else:
    print("there is no class of 'Label' or no attribute of 'href'! ")
```

this method can use to handle exception to prevent program crash.

if your page element is fixed, the former answer is feasible.