# How do I scrape the link from an <a> string in one line?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a web scraper and it has many different variables so keeping each variable to a single line is important to me. The current variable I am working on I have down to this:

```
<a href="http://website.com/example/123" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Is there any simple way I can simply get the website (`http://website.com/example/123` in this case) scrapped out in one line of code?

I'm currently using urllib, re, and BeautifulSoup so any of those libraries are fine. I tried adding

```
.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})
```

to the end of my line, but it made the output return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you have to do is yourVarName['href']:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="http://website.com/example/123" target="_blank">Example</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

Found the URL: http://website.com/example/123

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815888/3920284

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better answer, thank you!

Comment: or, alternatively `soup.select('a[href]')`.