# Extracting links from website using Python, NOT IN HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, screen-scraping, google-crawlers

I need to gather  PDF-files from this page: http://www.anp.gov.br/?id=532.

I wonder how this is possible in Python when I cant find the links in the HTML source code. Before I have found the links to such files by using Beautifulsoup and pandas.

Thanks for all kind of answers!

Comment: Can you explain why you can't find the links in the HTML source code? I'm not sure I'm clear on the goal here.

Comment: Hi, Alex W! 

The developers that made the page have not written the links directly in the HTML source code, but are called when clicked. I want these links to collect all the data, and merge them into one excel sheet. 

Thanks for the respond btw!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like all of the pdf links are in `<a>` tags so you can use BeautifulSoup to grab those links. If you need further advice I recommend you reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815888/2594119) discussion to see how to accomplish that task.

[image]

Comment: The problem is just that the links is not in <a> tags.

Comment: Check the image I uploaded. I can see the links to the files, hopefully you can as well! If so, you can reference the discussion I linked to in order to get the url from the `href` in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Found it now!