# How to get href in webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 articles = contents.find_all('article')
 for article in articles:
     titles=article.find('div',{"class":"featured"})
     print(titles)
```

This is giving the output as

```
<div class="featured" style="background-image: url(https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Mint-Oreo-Cheesecake-1-of-1-350x500.jpg)"> <a href="https://therecipecritic.com/2018/02/mint-oreo-cheesecake/" rel="bookmark"><span class="readpost">View the Recipe</span></a></div>
```

Here how can I get the href of the element **a**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close. You can access the `href` by accessing the builtin `__getitem__` method of the results returned from finding the `a` attributes:

```
print(titles.find('a')['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access first the `a` tag and then access it's `href` attribute like you would with a dictionary:

```
>>> titles.a['href']
'https://therecipecritic.com/2018/02/mint-oreo-cheesecake/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin cats with Python. Here is how I do it...

```
wsHREF = wsArticle.find("<<tag>>", re.compile("<<classname>>.*")).attrs['href']
```

where '`wsArticle`' is my BSoup object of a node of elements, `<<tag>>` is your HTML tag to find, and `<<classname>>` is your `class` to search for, but I use a wildcard to find everything starting with... myclass... etc.