# ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, anaconda

I know this question has been asked a lot on this site, but I have tried all of the solutions given, and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

For starters: I am on a `Windows 10` computer using `Python 3.6`. I installed `Anaconda`  as my IDE.

I tried to install `BeautifulSoup4` with `pip` install `beautifulsoup4`, but I got the

> Requirement already satisfied

response.

The code I am trying to run is just

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4

to which I get the error: ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4' 

The full error is:
runfile('C:/Users/ter/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/ter/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-8717178e85e1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/ter/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/ter/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\ter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\ter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/ter/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4

ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4'
```

Here is what I have tried to resolve this problem:

  1. Since 90% of the solutions I have found were because someone had named a file `bs4.py`, I checked for that. However this was the very first file I had made on this computer which was just named `untitled1.py`. Later on (last thing I did) out of frustration I deleted every instance of bs4 and beautiful from my computer, and the problem persisted, so another file being named `bs4` is definitely not the issue.

2. I tried just importing `bs4` (import `bs4`). That works perfectly fine, or at least it does not lead to any errors.
3. I changed the directories around. The `bs4` file is currently in the default `Anaconda` folder. I then changed the CD to the location of the project file and even tried copying and pasting the `bs4`, `bs4-0.0.1.dist-info`, and `beautifulsoup4-4.6.3.dist-info` files into the project file directory. Nothing really changed there.
4. I also did `pip3` install `bs4`. I don't know if that's necessary, but I did that as well.
5. I reinstalled all of these multiple times including `Anaconda` once and `bs4/beautifulsoup` 7 or 8 times, including a few uses of `pip install --upgrade -force-reinstall beautifulsoup4`.

Anyways, I hope this helps describe the problem. Let me know if I can provide any further information.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me!

Comment: There is no `BeautifulSoup4`, it's just `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Blender mentioned is just BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="some_url">next</a>
<span class="class"><a href="another_url">later</a></span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

**Output**

```
Found the URL: some_url
Found the URL: another_url
```

The above code was taken as example from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)