# Installation of BS4 successful, python not recognising

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I hope that you are well. I have tried searching the other threads about my issue, but I have yet to find a solution. Attached below are the screenshots of my work and methods to install the bs4 module, and the error I encounter. I am more than willing to attach more screenshots if required.
[Here is the command prompt telling me that the installation was successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I90C.png)

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4 as beauti

url = 'https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s?max_rows=500'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
for cell in row.findAll('td'):
    text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
    list_of_cells.append(text)
list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Last", "First", "Middle", "Gender", "Race", "Age", "City", "State"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Below is IDLE giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aditi\Desktop\webscraper.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4 as beauti
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\aditi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's spelling mistake in the import statement!

It's **BeautifulSoup** and not BeautifulSoup4

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as beauti
```

**EDIT**

Also I would  recommend to stick to what you import like,

1. You are importing BeautifulSoup4 but in this line below, you are using BeautifulSoup() and not BeautifulSoup4()

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   ```
2. Importing BeautifulSoup4 as beauti and not using the variable 'beauti' anywhere.

We mostly stick with BeautifulSoup() and I also recommend you to do so.

I just found that this issue was previously asked and resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067954/importerror-cannot-import-name-beautifulsoup4), check it out!

Comment: I have tried using BeautifulSoup, yet it gives me the same error, I read that BeautifulSoup4 is for python versions above python 2

Comment: The url you have put up in the code is not working for me, can you check if it's accessible for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help, you were right in the end aha! I followed what you said, and it worked for me. Once again, thank you Ananth :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo use BeautifulSoup instead of BeautifulSoup4.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://report.boonecountymo.org/mrcjava/servlet/SH01_MP.I00290s?max_rows=500'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})
# collect all rows except details and last row
total_items = [row.text.strip().split()[:-1] for row in table.find_all('tr')[:-1] ] # list of list

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

writer.writerow(["Last", "First", "Middle", "Gender", "Race", "Age", "City", "State"])
for row in total_items:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Yep! I got it wrong, I followed the wrong manual! Thank you very much for helping Samsul! :)

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it correctly solved your issue :)