# Scraping returning only one value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to scrape something as my first program, just to learn the basics really but I'm having trouble showing more than one result.

The premise is going to a forum (http://blackhatworld.com), scrape all thread titles and compare with a string. If it contains the word "free" it will print, otherwise it won't.

Here's the current code:

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.blackhatworld.com/')
content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
threadtitles = content.find_all('a', class_='PreviewTooltip')


n=0
for x in range(len(threadtitles)):
    test = list(threadtitles)[n]
    test2 = list(test)[0]
    if test2.find('free') == -1:
        n=n+1
    else:
        print(test2)
        n=n+1
```

This is the result of running the program:
https://i.gyazo.com/6cf1e135b16b04f0807963ce21b2b9be.png

As you can see it's checking for the word "free" and it works but it only shows first result while there are several more in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, strings comparison is case sensitive (`FREE != free`). To solve your problem, first you need to put `test2` in lowercase:

```
test2 = list(test)[0].lower()
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem and simplify your code try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.blackhatworld.com/')
content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
threadtitles = content.find_all('a', class_='PreviewTooltip')

count = 0

for title in threadtitles:
    if "free" in title.get_text().lower():
        print(title.get_text())
    else:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

**Bonus:** Print value of `href`:

```
for title in threadtitles:
    print(title["href"])
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href).

Comment: the count should be in the else and print above for what I intended but yes that really is a lot simpler lol, didn't know about the get_text function, it really does make things a lot simpler. If only you know how long I spent thinking about this whole array stuff >.<

Comment: I know it's not relevant to this thread but do you know if there's a way to pull the value of the 'href' tag inside the 'a' tag?