# Get href from html with Beautiful Soup select or lxml xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing some web scraping on the Rotten Tomatoes website, for [example here](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/leto).

I am using Python with the Beautiful Soup and lxml modules together.

I want to extract the movie info, for example:
   - Genre: Drama, Musical & Performing Arts

- Directed By: Kirill Serebrennikov
- Written By: Mikhail Idov, Lili Idova, Ivan Kapitonov, Kirill Serebrennikov, Natalya Naumenko
- **Written by (links)**: /celebrity/michael_idov, /celebrity/lily_idova, /celebrity/ivan_kapitonov, /celebrity/kirill_serebrennikov, /celebrity/natalya_naumenko

I inspected the page html to get the guidelines on the paths:

```
                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                        <div class="meta-label subtle">Rating: </div>
                        <div class="meta-value">NR</div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                        <div class="meta-label subtle">Genre: </div>
                        <div class="meta-value">

                                <a href="/browse/opening/?genres=9">Drama</a>, 

                                <a href="/browse/opening/?genres=12">Musical &amp; Performing Arts</a>

                        </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                        <div class="meta-label subtle">Directed By: </div>
                        <div class="meta-value">

                                <a href="/celebrity/kirill_serebrennikov">Kirill Serebrennikov</a>

                        </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                        <div class="meta-label subtle">Written By: </div>
                        <div class="meta-value">

                                <a href="/celebrity/michael_idov">Mikhail Idov</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/lily_idova">Lili Idova</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/ivan_kapitonov">Ivan Kapitonov</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/kirill_serebrennikov">Kirill Serebrennikov</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/natalya_naumenko">Natalya Naumenko</a>

                        </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                        <div class="meta-label subtle">In Theaters: </div>
                        <div class="meta-value">
                            <time datetime="2019-06-06T17:00:00-07:00">Jun 7, 2019</time>
                            <span style="text-transform:capitalize">&nbsp;limited</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>




                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                        <div class="meta-label subtle">Runtime: </div>
                        <div class="meta-value">
                            <time datetime="P126M">
                                126 minutes
                            </time>
                        </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="meta-row clearfix">
                    <div class="meta-label subtle">Studio: </div>
                    <div class="meta-value">

                            <a href="http://sonypictures.ru/leto/" target="movie-studio">Gunpowder &amp; Sky</a>

                    </div>

            </li>
```

I created the html objects like this:

```
    page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
    tree = html.fromstring(page_response.content)
```

For the Writer, for example, as I only need the text on the element, it fairly easy to get:

```
page_content.select('div.meta-value')[3].getText()
```

Or using the xpart for the Rating:

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="meta-value"]/text()')[0]
```

For the desired Writer Links, where I have the issue, to access the html chunk I do this:

```
page_content.select('div.meta-value')[3]
```

Which gives:

```
<div class="meta-value">
<a href="/celebrity/michael_idov">Mikhail Idov</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/lily_idova">Lili Idova</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/ivan_kapitonov">Ivan Kapitonov</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/kirill_serebrennikov">Kirill Serebrennikov</a>, 

                                <a href="/celebrity/natalya_naumenko">Natalya Naumenko</a>
```

Or:

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="meta-value"]')[3]
```

Giving:

```
<Element div at 0x2915a4c54a8>
```

The problem is that I can't extract the 'href'. The output I want is:

```
/celebrity/michael_idov, /celebrity/lily_idova, /celebrity/ivan_kapitonov, /celebrity/kirill_serebrennikov, /celebrity/natalya_naumenko
```

I have tried:

```
page_content.select('div.meta-value')[3].get('href')
tree.xpath('//div[@class="meta-value"]')[3].get('href')
tree.xpath('//div[@class="meta-value"]/@href')[3]
```

All with a null or error result.
Could anyone help me out on this?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href

Comment: Thanks. That returns all the hrefs in the page, however I just want those on the section page_content.select('div.meta-value')[3]
Any tip for this?
I tried, with no success, something like:
for a in page_content.select('div.meta-value')[2]:
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following scripts to get the content you are interested in. Make sure to test both of them by using different movies. I suppose they both will produce the desired output. I tried to avoid any hardcoded indices to target the content.

Using css selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/leto')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

directed = soup.select_one(".meta-row:contains('Directed By') > .meta-value > a").text
written = [item.text for item in soup.select(".meta-row:contains('Written By') > .meta-value > a")]
written_links = [item.get("href") for item in soup.select(".meta-row:contains('Written By') > .meta-value > a")]
print(directed,written,written_links)
```

Using xpath:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

r = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/leto')
root = fromstring(r.text)

directed = root.xpath("//*[contains(.,'Directed By')]/parent::*/*[@class='meta-value']/a/text()")
written = root.xpath("//*[contains(.,'Written By')]/parent::*/*[@class='meta-value']/a/text()")
written_links = root.xpath(".//*[contains(.,'Written By')]/parent::*/*[@class='meta-value']/a//@href")
print(directed,written,written_links)
```

In case of cast, I used list comprehension so that I can use `.strip()` on individual element to kick out whitespaces. `normalize-space()` is the ideal option for this, though.

```
cast = [item.strip() for item in root.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'cast-item')]//a/span[@title]/text()")]
```

Comment: The xpath work flawlessly, thanks so much.
Anyway I have no clue how you got it. Any short (I don't want to ask too much) explanation of the syntax or some resource you would advise to check?
Thanks again!

Comment: Initially check out the content of [this link](https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/) to get a basic understanding as to how you can create relative xpaths.

Comment: SIM, if it's not asking too much, would you help me with one more, please? I really couldn't understand the syntax.
To get the list of cast (Teo Yoo, Irina Starshenbaum , etc.) I looked hard at the html and the guide you sent me but I couldn't come up with something useful.
Would you please give me a hand in here? I really tried. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to include cast @spcvalente .

Comment: You ARE great indeed! I would gladly pay you a beer. I think with this examples I'll be able to adapt and use it for other pages.

Thank you ever so much.