# Getting href with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get info from a table. There are some links inside the td's, and in this case, I would retrieve the **href=""** content rather than the td text itself.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
url = 'http://www.milavia.net/airshows/calendar/showdates-2020-world.html'

page = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

tableOutput = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    date, event, location, website, facebook, feature, notes = row.find_all('td')[0:7]
    # print(website)
    p = {
        'Date': date.text.strip(),
        'Event': event.text.strip(),
        'Location': location.text.strip(),
        # 'Site': website.text.strip(),
        'Site': website.select('a', href=True, text='TEXT'),
        'Facebook': facebook.text.strip(),
        'Featuring': feature.text.strip(),
        'Notes': notes.text.strip()
    }
    tableOutput.append(p)
print(tableOutput)
```

Here is the output:

```
[{'Data': '15-18 Jan', 'Evento': 'Kuwait Aviation Show', 'Local': 'Kuwait International Airport, Kuwait', 'Site': [<a class="asclnk" href="http://kuwaitaviationshow.com/" target="airshow" title="Visit Kuwait Aviation Show Website: kuwaitaviationshow.com">link</a>], 'Facebook': '', 'Atração': '', 'Obs.': 'public 17-18'}, {'Data': '18 Jan', 'Evento': 'Classics of the Sky Tauranga City Airshow', 'Local': 'Tauranga, New Zealand', 'Site': [<a class="asclnk" href="http://www.tcas.nz" target="airshow" title="Visit Classics of the Sky Tauranga City Airshow Website: www.tcas.nz">link</a>], 'Facebook': '', 'Atração': '', 'Obs.': ''}, {'Data': 'Date', 'Evento': 'Event', 'Local': 'Location', 'Site': [], 'Facebook': 'Facebook', 'Atração': 'Feature', 'Obs.': 'Notes'}]
```

I'm unable to get only the text inside href, e.g.

```html
<a class="asclnk" href="http://www.tcas.nz" target="airshow" title="Visit Classics of the Sky Tauranga City Airshow Website: www.tcas.nz">
```

I have tried some approaches using `website.select()` or `website.find()`, but none of them gave me the result I needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Comment: Thank you, @JosephRajchwald. I have tested all the solutions on the mentioned post, and none of them gave me a different result I had before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the reference link you have tried not worked because you have iterating rows and some of the rows has no anchor tag href attribute so it gets failed. I have provided an if condition to check.Try now.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.milavia.net/airshows/calendar/showdates-2020-world.html'
session=requests.session()
page = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

tableOutput = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    date, event, location, website, facebook, feature, notes = row.find_all('td')[0:7]
    if website.select_one('a[href]'):
        p = {
           'Date': date.text.strip(),
           'Event': event.text.strip(),
           'Location': location.text.strip(),
           # 'Site': website.text.strip(),
           'Site': website.select_one('a[href]')['href'],
           'Facebook': facebook.text.strip(),
           'Featuring': feature.text.strip(),
           'Notes': notes.text.strip()
            }
        tableOutput.append(p)
print(tableOutput)
```

**Output**:

```
[{'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Kuwait International Airport, Kuwait', 'Site': 'http://kuwaitaviationshow.com/', 'Date': '15-18 Jan', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Kuwait Aviation Show', 'Notes': 'public 17-18'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Tauranga, New Zealand', 'Site': 'http://www.tcas.nz', 'Date': '18 Jan', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Classics of the Sky Tauranga City Airshow', 'Notes': ''}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh, India', 'Site': 'https://defexpo.gov.in/', 'Date': '05-08 Feb', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Defexpo India 2020', 'Notes': 'public Sat. 8th'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Changi Exhibition Centre, Singapore', 'Site': 'http://www.singaporeairshow.com/', 'Date': '11-16 Feb', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Singapore Airshow 2020', 'Notes': 'public Sat-SunReports: 2018 2014'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Al Bateen Executive Airport, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'Site': 'http://www.adairexpo.com/', 'Date': '04-06 Mar', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Abu Dhabi Air Expo & Heli Expo 2020', 'Notes': 'trade expo'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': "Djerba–Zarzis Int'l Airport, Djerba, Tunisia", 'Site': 'http://www.iadetunisia.com/en/', 'Date': '04-08 Mar', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'IADE Tunisia 2020', 'Notes': 'public days 7-8'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Tyabb Airport, Tyabb VIC, Australia', 'Site': 'http://www.tyabbairshow.com/', 'Date': '08 Mar', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Tyabb Air Show 2020', 'Notes': ''}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Echuca Airport, Echuca VIC, Australia', 'Site': 'http://www.antique-aeroplane.com.au/', 'Date': '20-22 Mar', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'AAAA National Fly-in', 'Notes': ''}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': "Santiago Int'l Airport, Santiago, Chile", 'Site': 'http://www.fidae.cl/', 'Date': '31 Mar / 05 Apr', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'FIDAE 2020', 'Notes': 'public Apr 4-5'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': "Santiago Int'l Airport, Santiago, Chile", 'Site': 'http://www.fidae.cl/', 'Date': '31 Mar / 05 Apr', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'FIDAE 2020', 'Notes': 'public Apr 4-5'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Wanaka Airport, Otago, New Zealand', 'Site': 'http://www.warbirdsoverwanaka.com/', 'Date': '11-13 Apr', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Warbirds Over Wanaka 2020', 'Notes': 'Report 2010'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Illawarra Regional Airport, Wollongong NSW, Australia', 'Site': 'http://www.woi.org.au/', 'Date': '02-03 May', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Wings over Illawarra', 'Notes': ''}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'AFB Waterkloof, Centurion, South Africa', 'Site': 'http://www.aadexpo.co.za/', 'Date': '16-20 Sep', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Africa Aerospace & Defence - AAD 2020', 'Notes': 'public 19-20'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'JIExpo Kemayoran, Jakarta, Indonesia', 'Site': 'http://www.indoaerospace.com/', 'Date': '04-07 Nov', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Indo Aerospace 2020', 'Notes': 'trade only'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Zhuhai, Guangdong, China', 'Site': 'http://www.airshow.com.cn/', 'Date': '10-15 Nov', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Airshow China 2020', 'Notes': 'public 13-15th'}, {'Featuring': '', 'Location': 'Sakhir Air Base, Bahrain', 'Site': 'http://www.bahraininternationalairshow.com/', 'Date': '18-20 Nov', 'Facebook': '', 'Event': 'Bahrain International Airshow BIAS 2020', 'Notes': ''}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your filtering with css up front. With bs4 4.7.1 you can ensure you work only with rows containing those links by using `:has`. This reduces the lines of code and remove need for indexing. If you use `select` you can leverage `limit` argument.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.milavia.net/airshows/calendar/showdates-2020-world.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

tableOutput = []
for row in soup.select('tr:has(.asclnk[href])'):
    date, event, location, website, facebook, feature, notes = row.select('td',limit=7)

    p = {
       'Date': date.text.strip(),
       'Event': event.text.strip(),
       'Location': location.text.strip(),
       'Site': website.select_one('a[href]')['href'],
       'Facebook': facebook.text.strip(),
       'Featuring': feature.text.strip(),
       'Notes': notes.text.strip()
        }
    tableOutput.append(p)
print(tableOutput)
```