# Need to remove the tags in the filtered parsed HTML link

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

After selecting one required link from many, need to further pass this link to a `DataFrame` to extract the numbers.

My code is as below:

```
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
tags=soup.select_one(a[href*=mar]') *** Out of Jan, Feb and Mar links, the line filters for a link that has Mar in it.
```

Now i am getting "'a href="http://someurl.xlsx">March (12kb, Excel)"'

I need only "http://someurl.xlsx" to pass to a `DataFrame` for reading the content of Excel page.

Comment: See this similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Try the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a href="http://someurl.xlsx">March (12kb, Excel)</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

tags = soup.select('a')[0].get('href')
print(tags)
```

---

> ```
> http://someurl.xlsx
> ```

Comment: Thank You. First I had to typecast “bs4.element.Tag” to String and then apply formula.