# How to slice the required link from beautifulsoup outcome

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying web scraping using beautifulsoup. i am trying to get this as the output

`<div class="links" data-v-6be015a6=""><a class="card-link" data-v-6be015a6="" href="/istanbul-beylikduzu-cumhuriyet-satilik/daire/93096-835"></a></div>`>

how can i cut only the link (istanbul-beylikduzu-cumhuriyet-satilik/daire/93096-835) out of it ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

page = 'https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/istanbul-satilik?sortField=PRICE&sortDirection=ASC&p31=200000&p33=1&page=1'
source = requests.get(page).text
    
soup= BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'links'})
print(link)
```

Comment: What link would you like to extract? At the first glance I couldn't identify any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Answer (score 0):

**Example - Use `['href']`**

```
import bs4

html = '''<div class="links" data-v-6be015a6=""><a class="card-link" data-v-6be015a6="" href="/istanbul-beylikduzu-cumhuriyet-satilik/daire/93096-835"></a></div>>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print( "Found the URL:", a['href'])
```