# getting incorrect HTML content of a page using urlib and request

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests, robotframework, urllib

I used two methods to get Page Source of an internal application link.

1. first Method -
   used Robot Framework Keyword
   ${html_page} =.  Get Source
2. Second Method -

   - using request --
     visit_url_content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
     and
   - visit_url_content = requests.get(url, 'html.parser').text

After getting page source i am extracting all links with tag a and attribute as 'href' using beautifulsoup.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

with first method i get about 20 links but with second method i get 2 links only...
I need to process this in python so cannot use robot framework option.
Any help as to why it might be happening

Comment: why -1 on this question?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear how your code exactly looks like, since you only posted a few code snippets. I assume it looks something like this:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "your-url"

html = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read().decode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(a["href"])
```

Based on StackOverflow: [BeautifulSoup getting href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href)

Does this code differ in some way from yours? Can you share the complete code of yours that crawls the website / the URL you want to crawl? Otherwise it is hard to find out what the problem is.