# Scraping through subsections of a web page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium to scrape links from a web page. The problem is that there are tabs on the page to select different subsections (Scene 1, Scene 2 etc.). The relevant links are hidden behind this subsection. The html remains the same.
With my following code I only get the link for the first subsection.

```
download_page_links = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@href]")
download_page_links_href = [e.get_attribute("href") for e in download_page_links]
```

The html code if subsection 1 is selected looks like this:

```
<ul class="fivecol last"> == $0
   <li>
      <a href='#' id="scene0" class="selected">1</a>
   <li>
   <li>
      <a href='#' id="scene1" class>2</a>
   <li>
```

The html code if subsection 2 is selected looks like this:

```
<ul class="fivecol last"> == $0
   <li>
      <a href='#' id="scene0" class>1</a>
   <li>
   <li>
      <a href='#' id="scene1" class="selected">2</a>
   <li>
```

How can I scrap through the different subsections?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815888

Comment: This is a tricky one. May I know the website to figure out if this is indeed hidden from the DOM? If it's in another iframe or something, maybe this link will help you.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: What happens when you execute your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers. I have solved the problem as follows:

```
    scene_list = []
    for n in range(0, 20):
        try:
            scene_list.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "scene' + str(n) + '"]'))

        except:
            pass

    for scene in scene_list:
        scene.click()
        download_page_links = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@href]")
        download_page_links_href = [e.get_attribute("href") for e in download_page_links]
```

I let the script click on each scene, thereby enabling the links to appear. Then I scan the page for the appropriate links.